# Codeblocks gsl issue (probably linking)

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, gsl

When using Codeblocks on Windows 7 with Cygwin compiler and precompiled library GnuWin32 (gsl-1.8) and try using functions (e.g. when including gsl_sf_bessel.h, then using gsl_sf_bessel_J0), the compiler always complains about not finding it:

> undefined reference to gsl_sf_bessel_J0
>   R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol 'gsl_sf_bessel_J0'
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

I linked libgslcblas.a and libgsl.a from the .\lib - folder of GnuWin32, in both orders, both with and without -Wall -Wextra -g arguments, putting also libgsl.dll and  libgslcblas.dll both into the directory of my program and into System32. Nothing worked.

My very basic example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main(void) {

    double xx = 5.0;
    double yy = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (xx);
    printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", xx, yy);

    return 0;
}
```

The includes work perfectly well. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the command line generated by CodeBlocks and see if it is really including the libraries that you want

Comment: Where is that message/how can I call it?

Comment: You have window, at the botton of the IDE main window, called "Logs & Others". Click on "Build messages"

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and the errors mentioned above are put in there. So apparently, the "ld returned 1 exit status" refers to the linking. Now what can I do about that?

Comment: Im suggesting to look at command line generated by the compiler, not only the error message

Comment: The only other tab where anything is written is the BuildLog, where it says 

"g++.exe  -o bin/Debug/harmonic1.exe obj/Debug/main.o  -Wall  M:/Programming/C++/Libraries/GnuWin32/lib/libgsl.a M:/Programming/C++/Libraries/GnuWin32/lib/libgslcblas.a
obj/Debug/main.o: In function `main': 

...continuing with the aforementioned error messages.

Comment: So, I would see if in `M:/Programming/C++/Libraries/GnuWin32/lib/` there are both `libgsl.a` and `libgslcblas.a` in it. If they exist, your problem could be with the gsl package itself

Answer (score 0):

I installed now also **MinGW**, just the basics with compiler and linker, and **it works** now! So, the issue is obviously that for some reason, Cygwin could not link the libraries.

I do not understand why my question got downvoted, as I think that this is really an issue which is neither obvious, nor addressed in this form in any other question.